# Using relative path in yaml file for id_rsa file

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to use "~/.ssh/id_rsa" as the key path in cluster.yaml to deploy a kubernetes cluster but when it's called, the error says 'No such file or directory: ~/.ssh/id_rsa'

```
node_defaults:
  keyfile: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  username: "nikhil"

nodes:
  - name: "k8s-control-plane"
    address: "10.0.0.1"
    internal_address: "192.***.**.***"
    roles: ["control-plane", "worker"]

cluster_name: "k8s-stack.testcluster.com"
```

It works fine if i use absolute path for keyfile:(/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa) but facing issue while using relative path like this

Comment: That's not a relative path, it's a tilde expansion. That is a shell feature, YAML is not a shell. What's the problem with writing the absolute path?

Comment: Its clear if you can provide bit of context around what you are trying to do. This will give the reader a clear picture which tool you are facing the issue with.

Comment: "but when it's called" - what does that mean? How do you "call" that yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Some environment variables are available in Ansible. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

    - command: whoami
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout

    - command: echo $HOME
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout

    - debug:
        var: ansible_env
```

shows the environment variables collected by *setup (gather_facts: true)*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: admin

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: /home/admin

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_env:
    BLOCKSIZE: K
    HOME: /home/admin
    LANG: C.UTF-8
    LOGNAME: admin
    MAIL: /var/mail/admin
    MM_CHARSET: UTF-8
    PATH: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/admin/bin
    PWD: /home/admin
    SHELL: /bin/sh
    SSH_CLIENT: 10.1.0.184 58084 22
    SSH_CONNECTION: 10.1.0.184 58084 10.1.0.61 22
    SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/1
    TERM: xterm-256color
    USER: admin

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Notes

- Some environment variables are available in the configuration files.
- See [How do I access shell environment variables?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables)
- See [Running under fakeroot](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#running-under-fakeroot)